# Does ActiveCollab subversion integration work with subversion over ssh?

Tags: svn, project-management, integration, activecollab

I'm trying to setup a repository in an ActiveCollab project. During setup, it reports that the  connection tests successfully. However, when I try to actually update the repository, I get the following message:

**Could not obrain the highest revision number for the given repository.**

If I try to browse the repository, the following error comes up:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getRevision() on a non-object in /u/sites/activecollab/webroot/shared/activecollab/activecollab/application/modules/source/controllers/RepositoryController.class.php on line 357

Is this because of trying to access the repository via svn+ssh plugin rather than http? Or did something happen on the ActiveCollab end? The repository is accessed fine via other means -- only ActiveCollab has the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ActiveCollab, they do not support this. The svn plugin has to be either over http or, if ActiveCollab is on the same server as the repository, directly using the file://path/to/repository link.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I'm able to use svn+ssh from AC to another server. For me it was svn+ssh://username@server.ext/path/to/repo

Because AC requires you to enter a username and password, I supplied a username/pass combo that I set up in the passwd file. Also make sure your user has the appropriate permissions in authz. The second part was making sure the web user (server) id_rsa key is added to the svn server's user account.